# C++ cast derived class pointer from base class pointer

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

The following code: https://godbolt.org/z/eYEdTnMqc

```cpp
#include<memory>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

class Base {
  protected:
    std::string type;
};
class Derived1 : public Base{
  protected:
    bool status;
  public:
    Derived1(): status(false), type("Derived1") {}
    void setStatus(bool newStatus) {
      status = newStatus;
    }
    bool getStatus() {
      return status;
    }
};

int main() {
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> vars;

  vars.push_back(std::make_shared<Derived1>());
  if(!vars.back()->getStatus()) {
    vars.back()->setStatus(true);
  }
}
```

Is giving me this compilation error:

```c
Could not execute the program
Compiler returned: 1
Compiler stderr
<source>: In constructor 'Derived1::Derived1()':
<source>:13:32: error: class 'Derived1' does not have any field named 'type'
   13 |     Derived1(): status(false), type("Derived1") {}
      |                                ^~~~
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:26:20: error: 'using element_type = class Base' {aka 'class Base'} has no member named 'getStatus'
   26 |   if(!vars.back()->getStatus()) {
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~
<source>:27:18: error: 'using element_type = class Base' {aka 'class Base'} has no member named 'setStatus'
   27 |     vars.back()->setStatus(true);
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~
```

My Base class has other derived classes that do not have getStatus() and setStatus() methods, so I don't want to make them virtual in the Base class.

EDIT1: I've edited the code and compile error to clear away stupid mistakes on my part while keeping the thrust of this question and the solution intact. Basically I need to use std::shared_ptr and to use std::static_pointer_cast when accessing the item inside the vector. Thanks @remy

EDIT2: As @remy pointed out below, static_cast/dynamic_cast to a raw pointer is fine since I don't intend to share ownership. So I should revert to std::unique_ptr and use dynamic_cast. So the solution would be the code below:

https://godbolt.org/z/4Yz94z7bb

```cpp
#include<memory>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

class Base {
  protected:
    std::string type;
};
class Derived1 : public Base{
  protected:
    bool status;
  public:
    Derived1(): status(false) {}
    void setStatus(bool newStatus) {
      status = newStatus;
    }
    bool getStatus() {
      return status;
    }
};

int main() {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> vars;

  vars.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived1>());
  static_cast<Derived1*>(vars.back().get())->setStatus(true);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In the code you have shown, `Derived1` does not actually derive from `Base`, so you can't assign a `Derived1*` pointer to a `Base*` pointer, and thus can't move a `std::unique_ptr<Derived1>` into a `std::unique_ptr<Base>`.

Change this:

```cpp
class Derived1 {
```

To this:

```cpp
class Derived1 : public Base {
```

And then for good measure, you should mark `Derived1::getStatus()` as `override`:

```cpp
bool getStatus() override {
    return status;
}
```

Now, that being said, since you are storing `Base` pointers in your `vector`, your code will still fail to compile because there is no `setStatus()` method defined in `Base`, so this statement is invalid:

```cpp
vars.back()->setStatus(true);
```

`vars.back()` will return a reference to a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` object, and then calling `operator->` on that object will return a `Base*` pointer, not a `Derived1*` pointer.  So, you would need to cast the `Base*` pointer back to `Derived1*` in order to access the `Derived1::setStatus()` method:

```cpp
static_cast<Derived1*>(vars.back().get())->setStatus(true);
```

You should add a virtual `setStatus()` method to `Base` for `Derived1` to override. Then you won't need the cast anymore:

```cpp
class Base {
  public:
    virtual bool getStatus() {
      return false;
    }
    virtual void setStatus(bool newStatus) {
    }
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
  protected:
    bool status;
  public:
    Derived1(): status(false) {}

    bool getStatus() override {
      return status;
    }

    void setStatus(bool newStatus) override {
      status = newStatus;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm kicking myself for missing the actual derivation. However, I have a few follow-ups:
<br/>
1. The reason I didn't add getStatus and setStatus to Base is because I have other Derived classes that don't have <set|get>Status. When I call <get|set>Status, I know it's a Derived1 class that I happen to store there. So it seems I need the static_cast method.
2. You used static_cast on a raw pointer, but I used a std::unique_ptr. I've read that std::static_pointer_cast only upcasts and doesn't downcast. Is there a similar way to do this with std::unique_ptr?

Comment: @jkang 1. you are contradicting yourself, as your example shows `getStatus()` is virtual in `Base`. But in any case, if you have multiple derived classes then `dynamic_cast` would be more appropriate for your situation, eg: `Derived1 *derived = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(the_unique_ptr.get()); if (derived) { derived->(get|set)Status() as needed... }` 2. `static_pointer_cast` only works with `std::shared_ptr`, not with `std::unique_ptr`, hence the casting of raw pointers.

Comment: Very sorry. I need to change that. My Base class should not have a getStatus(). I'll edit that. Also, thanks for the differentiation. I think I'll use std::shared_ptr and std::static_pointer_cast? I've read elsewhere that static_pointer_cast can't be used for downcasting?

Comment: @jkang Don't use `shared_ptr` unless you actually need shared-ownership semantics. In your example, `unique_ptr` will suffice, so stick with `(static|dynamic)_cast` as needed. `static_pointer_cast` is just a wrapper for creating a new *proper* `shared_ptr` from a `static_cast`'ed pointer (using `shared_ptr`'s aliasing constructor), but it does handle downcasting just fine.